# Why my react-bootstrap ListGroup displayed differently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to compose a list group and below is my rendering code

```
render() {
        return (
            <ListGroup>
                <ListGroupItem header="paitent1" href='#' active>
                    session 1
                </ListGroupItem>
                <ListGroupItem header="paitent2" href='#'>
                    session 2
                </ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
        );
    }
```

It's quite simple but displayed ugly, my react-bootstrap is 0.32.1. What's wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have imported the library in your component but you still need to import css yourself.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

You could either import it in your index.html
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

or you could import it inside your src/index.js and let webpack handle combining your CSS